# How can I fix the python ffmpge subprocess error fix

Tags: python, subprocess

Unfortunately, I get an error in my python script when I want to send a ffmpge command via subprocess.

Here is the error

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Benutzer\Development\python\main.py", line 48, in <module>
>     sub = subprocess.run([subprocess_cmd])
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
>     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1025, in __init__
>     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1494, in
> _execute_child
>     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei
> nicht finden
```

and here the code of main python script

```
import subprocess
import os.path

SCRIPT_FILE = os.path.realpath(__file__)
DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_FILE)
DATA = '\src\img\\'
DATA2 = '\src\mp4\\'
SAVEFILE = DIRECTORY + DATA
SAVEFILE2 = DIRECTORY + DATA2


def make_plain_video(imagefile, mp4_file):

    background_image = imagefile
    plain_video = mp4_file
    ffmpeg_command1 = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "
    ffmpeg_command2 = "-c:v libx264 -t 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1080:1920 "

    subprocess_cmd = ffmpeg_command1 + background_image + ffmpeg_command2 + plain_video

    return subprocess_cmd

imagefile = SAVEFILE + "background.jpeg "
mp4_file = SAVEFILE2 + "plain_video.mp4 "
subprocess_cmd = make_plain_video(imagefile, mp4_file)
# TODO fix the subprocess error
sub = subprocess.run([subprocess_cmd])
print(subprocess_cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `subprocess.run()` must be a list where each argument is a separate list element. Don't concatenate everything into a single string, return a list from `make_plain_video()` and pass that to `subprocess.run()`.

```
def make_plain_video(imagefile, mp4_file):
    background_image = imagefile
    plain_video = mp4_file
    ffmpeg_command1 = ["ffmpeg", "-loop",  "1",  "-i"]
    ffmpeg_command2 = ["-c:v", "libx264", "-t", "60", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-vf", "scale=1080:1920"]
    subprocess_cmd = ffmpeg_command1 + [background_image] + ffmpeg_command2 + [plain_video]

    return subprocess_cmd

imagefile = SAVEFILE + "background.jpeg"
mp4_file = SAVEFILE2 + "plain_video.mp4"
subprocess_cmd = make_plain_video(imagefile, mp4_file)
sub = subprocess.run(subprocess_cmd)
print(subprocess_cmd)
```

Comment: The command "ffmpeg" is either misspelled or
could not be found. have you a idea ?

Comment: Have you installed `ffmpeg` and is it your PATH?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, i can self fix the Problem, i have make a BAT file